# Class C++ Error : "Virtual is not allowed"

Tags: c++, class

I have this header for a project I'm doing :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<exception>
using namespace std;

class InvalidException : public exception
{
private:
    string message; 

public:


    InvalidException(const char *message)
    {
        this->message = message;
    }


    virtual const char *catch_the_error const throw()
    {
        return this->message.c_str();
    }
};
```

And it says that virtual is not allowed here and I don't know why because my exception is made public. Can somebody please provide me an answer please ?

Comment: You forgot to add the function argument `()` specifier, just after `virtual const char *catch_the_error`, before your `const` and `throw()` specifiers,

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
virtual const char *catch_the_error const throw()
```

to

```
virtual const char *catch_the_error() const throw()
```